# Linkedin oauth2 r_liteprofile not being returned from api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, linkedin-api, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

So I have a rails app and I am using [this gem for oauth2](https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2). Now on the developer's console on linkedin I can only select

`r_basicprofile`, `r_emailaddress`, `rw_company_admin` and `w_share`.

So I have `r_basicprofile` selected.

Now once identified linkedin in pushing the user to `http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback?error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application&state=126bb5cb16613e67f77580954980f86e4a3080c7cb4e56fe`

which is clearly requesting `r_liteprofile`. Now since `r_liteprofile` is not allowed it gives a callback error

`OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError`

`unauthorized_scope_error | Scope &quot;r_liteprofile&quot; is not authorized for your application`.

routes.rb looks like

`get 'login-linkedin', to: redirect('/auth/linkedin')`

`get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#identify_network_entry'`

omniauth.rb looks like

`provider :linkedin, 'KEY', 'VALUE`

callback url in linkedin console for Oauth2.0 looks like

`http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback`

Is there a workaround or is this an implementation flaw ? This stopped happening sporadically so I am assuming I'm making an implementation error.

Comment: Hey, I don't know what's wrong with your stuff, but I myself and trying to get to a step you have already completed. It's a bit confusing for me trying to figure out how to test out the signin API's for OAuth2.0. It tells me I need to register an application but when I give it a URL that is something like: `http://localhost:3000` it tells me its not a valid URL. How did you get it to the point where you could make API requests for the credential tokens and such for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Today (jan 14th) linkedin transitioned their docs and allowed for all applications created after today to automatically be able to use r_liteprofile under the self serve section, but to use the r_basicprofile you'll have to apply to their partner program.

Connecting to the v1 API with r_basicprofile should work, but only until march 1st.

Perhaps your issue was happening because of the switch that took place.

Read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

> All new applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Platform as of January 14, 2019 can use LinkedIn's v2 APIs.

Specifically...

> What permissions do I have access to?
>
> LinkedIn v1 APIs provided the following set of permissions:
>
> r_basicprofile
>      r_emailaddress
>      w_share
>      rw_company_admin
>
> Moving forward, the available v2 APIs include:
>
> r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile)
>      r_emailaddress
>      w_member_social (replaces w_share)

and ...

> Looking to maintain access to the Basic Profile fields? Learn more about applying to a LinkedIn Partner Program.