# LinkedIn API v2 integration

Tags: integration, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn API v2 to the app I'm developing for my client and I need help with it. Basically, I need to allow users to fetch some of their LinkedIn profile data and save it to the platform. As I understood, the first version of the API will no longer be supported. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs

So, the problem is that the default field set I was able to retrieve is extremely limited. And it seems like I should apply for the Developer Program here to gain additional API access 
https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

I already submitted the application but haven't yet received any response. The frustrating part is that I'm not even sure if this is what I should do to get access.

Here's what I already discovered

Here it's said that the partner's program isn't available
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/97491

Here it sends me to the partner program
https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq
Should I choose marketing? https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

I suppose so because other options seem to be irrelevant. So I already applied here
https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

But still no answer

Here are the developers facing the same issues with no answer as well

```
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/712591
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/711176
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/711027
```

Here seems to be the answer to a similar question but still, no specific link or steps to apply for a partner's program
[LinkedIn API V2 - Can't get summary, skills and headline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286608/linkedin-api-v2-cant-get-summary-skills-and-headline)

Here they also tell about some partner's program but again without specifics
[Linkedin oauth2 r_liteprofile not being returned from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178931/linkedin-oauth2-r-liteprofile-not-being-returned-from-api)

Here in the official doc, it's also said that I should apply to the program (which I did)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

I applied on the 23rd of January and I'm still waiting for the approval without even knowing if this program will give me the API access I need

So I need to know one of the following

1. If my application will be approved it'll give me the extended access to the API v2 (r_fullprofile permission)
2. If the application I submitted isn't enough what else should I do in order to get the extended access to the API v2 (r_fullprofile permission)

It feels to be a simple process and I don't really understand why it has to involve the Marketing Developer Program when I only need to access some of the fields. I'm sure there is a reason for that. Could anybody from support provide some steps that I or my client should take on order to get the API access?

I already created the app as a developer here and successfully tested it
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps

So, just to be clear, the problem is not in something not working technically. It's just that I receive a very limited set of field of a user's profile and I need to expand it

Comment: 1. If your application will not approved then you can use only limited access you can't use r_fullprofile
2. I don't think you have any other option to user r_fullprofile if linkedin people will not approved your application

Comment: Hi! @KPSingh Can you confirm that this Marketing Developer Program is the thing I need? :) https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program#get-started

Comment: Aaaaand in 3 months they declined my application :)

Comment: Check what reason they have written you can modify your application according to his requirement then you can apply again

Comment: @KPSingh I would check it if it existed :) This is exactly what they answered
http://prntscr.com/nm4m0f